# Как программно изменить значение checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox

Как программно изменить значение `CheckBox` по умолчанию с неактивной галочкой.

```
 case R.id.action_check:

                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("checkbox", item.isChecked());
                    editor.commit();


                    if (item.isChecked()) {
                        mWebView.clearCache(true);

                        mWebView.reload();

                        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Увімкнена економія трафіку!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Економія трафіку вимкнена!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
```

Comment: Вам надо чтобы при запуске экрана настроек чекбокс показывал текущее значение из настроек? Или что непонятно?

Comment: `item.setChecked(!item.isChecked())`?

Answer (score 1):

Вот что вам нужно.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  if (item.getItemId() == R.id.checkbox){

      if(item.isChecked()){
          item.setChecked(false);
      }else{
          item.setChecked(true);
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: посмотрите второй комментарий под вопросом. строчка делает то же самое (инвертирует состояние чекбокса), но в 5 раз короче.

Comment: @pavlofff я знаю, показал для примера как можно использовать.
Для наглядности, чтобы человек понимал. Можно запугать его кодом в одну строку, если человек не знает как программно поставить.

Answer (score 0):

Если `item` это твой `CheckBox`, то сделать "галочку" активной:
в нужном месте прописать:

```
item.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: открывается и сразу закрывается приложение если так пишу

Comment: у меня не совсем checkbox а checkeble item может в этом проблема